# What does "CPU Minutes" mean exactly?

Tags: cluster, cpu-usage, hpc, slurm

I'm actually trying to report cluster utilization in Slurm but i don't understand the metric **CPU Minutes**.

```
[root@XXXX]# sreport cluster Utilization Start=2018-12-01 End=2018-12-31
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cluster Utilization 2018-12-01T00:00:00 - 2018-12-30T23:59:59
Usage reported in CPU Minutes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Cluster Allocate     Down PLND Dow      Idle Reserved  Reported
--------- -------- -------- -------- --------- -------- ---------
    linux   744460        0        0   8187049    54091   8985600
```

Am i supposed to divide that value by the numbers of threads/cpu ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The man page for `sreport` explains the different columns and the default format (`-t`) is Minutes.

> cluster Utilization
>
> This report will display total usage divided by Allocated, Down, Idle,
>   and Reserved time for selected clusters.  Reserved time refers to time
>   that a  job  was  waiting for resources after the job had become
>   eligible.  If the value is not of importance for you the number should
>   be grouped with idle time.

Your report period is 30 days having (30*24*60) 43200 minutes (December has 31 days / 44640 mins, but `End=<OPT>` defaults to the end of the previous day). 8985600 divided by 43200 makes 208. Does this correspond to the total amount of your CPUs or threads?

Comment: This is precisely the total amount of threads, thanks you ;-)